# How do you run a shell command in the background and suppress all output?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, gulp

I'm trying to write a Shell script (for use in Mac OSX Termninal) that will run a command to start a development server (gulp serve). I have it working except the server is continuously running so it doesn't allow me to enter subsequent commands in the same window without stopping the server (Control+C). My question is, is there a way I can run the process in the background and/or suppress any/all output?  My goal is to also write a 'stop server' command that will kill the process (which I'm also unsure how to do). I've tried all combinations of using ampersands and &>/dev/null and nothing quite works. Here's what I have so far:

```
if [ "$1" = "server" ]
then
  if [ "$2" = "on" ]
  then
    cd / & gulp serve --gulpfile /server/example/gulpfile.js # the output is still shown
    printf "\033[0;32mserver is online.\033[0m\n"
  else
    killall tail &>/dev/null 2>&1 # this doesn't kill the process
    printf "\033[0;32mportals is offline.\033[0m\n"
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing the output redirection on `killall`, not `gulp`, so `gulp` will continue to merrily split out text to your terminal.  Try instead:

```
cd / && gulp server --gulpfile /server/example/gulpfile.js >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Secondly, your kill command doesn't kill your process because you're not telling it to; you're asking it to kill all `tail` processes.  You want instead:

```
killall gulp
```

These modifications should be the most direct path to your goal.  However, there are a few additional things that may be useful to know.

Process management has a long history in the *nix world, and so we've been inventing tools to make this easier for a long time.  You can go through re-inventing them yourself (the next step would be to store the PID of your gulp process so that you can ensure you only kill it and not anything else with "gulp" in the name), or you can go all the way and write a system monitoring file.  For Linux, this would be SysV, Upstart, or systemd; I'm not sure what the OS X equivalent is.

However, since you're just doing this for development purposes, not a production website, you probably don't actually need that; your actual goal is to be able to execute ad-hoc shell commands while `gulp` is running.  You can use terminal tabs to do this, or more elegantly use the splitting capabilities of iTerm, `screen`, or `tmux`.  Tmux in particular is a useful tool for when you find yourself working a lot in a terminal, and would be a useful thing to become familiar with.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you for the answer and the detailed explanation! Thanks to @Diego Torres Milano as well!

Answer (score 1):

First, to run the process in the background

```
cd / && gulp serve --gulpfile /server/example/gulpfile.js > /tmp/gulp.log &
```

after `cd` you need `&&` (and) and `&` to run in the background at the end.

To kill all `gulp` processes

```
killall gulp
```

Comment: If you want to suppress *all* output, you should redirect `stderr` too. Something like: `gulp server --parms...... > /tmp/gulp.log 2>&1 &`. That says "redirect handle 2 (`stderror`) to the same place as handle 1 (`stdout`)". Order matters here, so it must be done after 1.